# order by is not working properly with two fields

Tags: mysql

this is my select  query i want to order by fetch record with two fields first and i want to order by with transType and after that with transDate 
  i am already given order by with this two fields but it is not working.

i know that there is something silly mistake but i can not find it

```
SELECT tranjectionId,date_format(transDate,'%d-%m-%Y') AS transDate,motiAmount,
                              transType,tranjection.partyId,item.itemName,gwt,loss,netwet,
                              party.partyName,melting,westage,finewet,rhodium,amount,bhav 
                         FROM  tranjection
                       LEFT JOIN party ON party.partyId =  tranjection.partyId
                       LEFT JOIN item ON item.itemId =  tranjection.itemId
                        WHERE tranjection.partyId = $_REQUEST['partyId']
                        AND transDate   >= '$fromDate'
                        AND transDate   <= '$toDate'
                        ORDER BY  transType = 'I',
                         transDate
```

Comment: What's the result and what are you trying to achieve with `transType = 'I'` in order by clause?

Comment: there are two transType one type is "I"  and second is "R" in result it shows me records whose tranjection type is "R"

Comment: order by transDate is working properly but there is issue with transType..

Comment: Do you understand, transType = 'I' is ordery by boolean ?

Comment: @LatikovDmitry if i am try to order by with transType = 'I' only it is not working..

Comment: u want to say that i can not order by with this field @LatikovDmitry

Comment: May be "... AND transDate   <= '$toDate' AND transType = 'I' ORDER BY  transDate" is what you want ?

Comment: transDate i am using for if i want to fetch record between this that is why here i am filter records on date wise.. @LatikovDmitry

Answer (score 1):

This is your `order by`:

```
ORDER BY  transType = 'I',
          transDate
```

The expression `transType = 'I'` is a boolean expression.  When interpreted as an integer, "0" is false, and "1" is true.  Hence, false values appear first in the sort, then true values.

You just want to sort descending:

```
ORDER BY  (transType = 'I') DESC,
          transDate
```

Comment: but still there is problem in sorting @Gordon Linoff

Comment: ORDER BY  (transType = 'R') ASC, transDate through that i get output which i want but i dont how it is working.

Comment: `(transType = 'R')` is a boolean, which is treated as an integer.  When true,it has a value of 1, when false, a value of 0.  So the values of "R" will be last.