# ORDER BY is not working properly in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The following is my `SELECT` query I want with `ORDER BY` with transType = 'I' and after that with transdate in ascending order. Through that query i can get  transType = 'I' record properly but after that it does not displays in proper sequence.

```
  SELECT tranjectionId,date_format(transDate,'%d-%m-%Y') AS transDate,motiAmount,
                             transType,tranjection.partyId,item.itemName,gwt,loss,netwet,
                              party.partyName,melting,westage,finewet,rhodium,amount,bhav 
                         FROM  tranjection,party,item
                       WHERE party.partyId =  tranjection.partyId
                       AND item.itemId =  tranjection.itemId
                         AND tranjection.partyId = ".$partyId."
                        ORDER BY  (transType = 'R') DESC,
                                   transDate
```

Comment: What is the point of Order by (tranType = 'R') ?

Comment: If you want 'I' why order by 'R'

Comment: `(tranType = 'R')` is `1` (true) for 'R', else `0` (false).  So the `R` rows will come out first (due to `DESC`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [order by is not working properly with two fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059260/order-by-is-not-working-properly-with-two-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While doing the order you may do as

```
order by 
case 
  when transtype = 'I' then 0 else 1 
end,
transdate;
```

Comment: still order by transDate is not proper @Abhik

Comment: Provide some example data and expected output.

Comment: If `transdate` is a DATETIME or DATE or TIMESTAMP, do _not_ call str_to_date.  If it is a `VARCHAR`, then does it begin with the _day_?  The use of `DATE_FORMAT` implies that it is not a VARCHAR, hence my downvote.

Comment: @RickJames apologies , my bad I read `date_format()` as `str_to_time()`

Comment: Well, you were "right" -- The OP redefined transDate, which is a confusing thing to do.

Comment: Well its my fault I really read `date_format()` as `str_to_time()` and hence in `order by`  I added `str_to_time`, thanks for pointing out that.